# Why does my MOSFET keep failing?

Tags: mosfet, tesla-coil

I am using the IRFZ44N MOSFET for my slayer exciter Tesla coil.
The primary has 3 turns and the secondary about 1000 turns. The high voltage output has no load connected, it's just dangling mid-air.

However, my mosfet doesn't blow when I disconnect the gate.

My input is 24 V at 2.5 A max.

This is my circuit

[image]
At first my circuit worked fine for a couple of months. Suddenly, every MOSFET I put in failed. I blew over 3 MOSFETs that way. When blown, all the pins of the MOSFET are shorted but there is no "magic smoke".

Can someone please tell me why the MOSFET started blowing up all of a sudden after working fine for so long?

Comment: I think you need to have a good hard think about what changed at your end. And I mean any change that might have a possible impact on things. Also, draw your actual circuit and show the power supply details and photograph the transformer and state the turns ratio and the type of wire you use. Also what is connected to the load end of the transformer?

Comment: Both the gate and source are connected to ground. Is it some kind of test?

Comment: If you're talking about the intersection at the wire from the primary coil and the wire from the secondary coil, it is fritzing's fault as it doesn't show the overlap there.

Comment: @Harish Gate and source, not drain and source. You've connected the gate to ground on the secondary side.

Comment: @Hearth I think that was my mistake. I saw a circuit with the low voltage of the secondary coil connected to ground and added it into the schematic. But my circuit doesn't actually have anything like that. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I've changed it.